# Derive squared angular momentum operator in spherical coordinates easily

Tags: tensors, differential-operators

there! I am studying tensor analysis and now try to apply it to solving a quantum physics problem.
Here I am trying to calculate angular momentum squared written in terms of the spherical coordinates directly.
Here is how it looks:

$\hat L^2=-\hbar^2(1/sin\theta\ \partial_\theta(sin\theta\ \partial_\theta)+1/sin^2\theta\ \partial_{\phi\phi})=-\hbar^2r^2(\nabla^2-1/r^2\ \partial_r(r^2\partial_r))$

And I can easily begin here:

$\begin{align}
\hat L^2&=(-i\hbar\vec r\times\nabla)^2\\
&=-\hbar^2r^2(\hat e_r\times\nabla)\bullet(\hat e_r\times\nabla)\\
&=-\hbar^2r^2(\hat e_r\bullet(\nabla\times(\hat e_r\times\nabla)))\\
&=-\hbar^2r^2(\hat e_r\bullet(\hat e_r \nabla^2-\nabla(\hat e_r\bullet\nabla)))\\
&=-\hbar^2r^2(\nabla^2-\hat e_r\bullet\nabla(\hat e_r\bullet\nabla))
\end{align}$

So there I confused, for time independent schrodinger function 
$\Phi(r,\theta,\phi)$
is a scalar function, and sperical coordinates is orthongonal everywhere, the form of $\nabla$ should be as simple as $\vec g^i\partial_{v^i}$ and then through a dot product it remains a scalar function $\partial_r$ again, and thus it finally turns into $\partial_{rr}$. So I cannot derive the correct expression.

Where am I wrong in deduction? And how can I derive the expression swiftly using tools of tensor analysis?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue is that $\hat e_r$ is not constant. Its direction changes with $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: @Andrei Yeah, I noticed that. But it is always orthogonal to the other two local axis and has a unit length. So I wonder if the dot product eradicates this change, and if not, how? ah, very confusing.

Comment: See for example http://www.thphys.nuim.ie/Notes/MP469/Laplace.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having learning a few more chapters in tensor analysis, now I can solve this question on my own! Here I post my answer.

The point is that covariant derivatives and covariant/contravariant as functions of coordiantes opponents are not commutable, so we should compute it totally in tensor language, or explicitly write down every commutation:

\begin{align}
\hat L^2&=(-i\hbar\vec r\times\nabla)^2\\
&=-\hbar^2\vec \epsilon:\vec r\nabla\cdot\vec \epsilon:\vec r\nabla\\
&=-\hbar^2\epsilon^{ijk}r_i\nabla_j\epsilon_{lmk}r^l\nabla^m\\
&=-\hbar^2(\delta^i_l\delta^j_m-\delta^i_m\delta^j_l)r_i\nabla_jr^l\nabla^m\\
&=-\hbar^2(r_i\nabla_jr^i\nabla^j-r_i\nabla_jr^j\nabla^i)\\
\end{align}

since $r^i=0, i\ne1$ in spherical coordinates, and $\nabla_jr^1=0, j\ne1$, so apply multiplication rule to it:
\begin{align}
r_i\nabla_jr^i\nabla^j-r_i\nabla_jr^j\nabla^i&=r_1\nabla_jr^1\nabla^j-r_1\nabla_1r^1\nabla^1\\
&=r^2\nabla_j\nabla^j-r^2\nabla_1\nabla^1\\
\end{align}

From this we give

$\hat L^2=-\hbar^2r^2(\nabla^2-1/r^2\ \partial_r(r^2\partial_r))$